# Issue with AJAX call to PHP file, mysql doesnt execute - with errors

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Don't really know what's the issue here. Probably something simple but might aswell get it out here. I have a form to register a user on a simple website, i send the information to register.php with AJAX, all values are sent properly. The form and the AJAX looks like the following:

```
        <form method="GET">
        <h4>Användarnamn:</h4>
        <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Användarnamn" name="reg-user">
        <h4>Välj lösenord:</h4>
        <input type="text" class="password" placeholder="Lösenord" name="reg-pass">
        <h4>Förnamn</h4>
        <input type="text" class="firstname" placeholder="Förnamn" name="reg-fn">
        <h4>Efternamn</h4>
        <input type="text" class="lastname" placeholder="Efternamn" name="reg-en"><br><br>
        <div class="btn btn-success reg-btn">Registrera</div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".reg-btn").click(function(){
        var username  = $(".username").val();
        var password  = $(".password").val();
        var firstname = $(".firstname").val();
        var lastname  = $(".lastname").val();

    //Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: "php/register.php",
        data:{ username: username, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },
        success: function(){
        $(".username").val("");
        $(".password").val("");
        $(".firstname").val("");
        $(".lastname").val("");
        $("#slide-register").prepend("<p>Användare registrerad.</p>");
}});
})
```

When this information is sent to the php, it tries to register the user, no errors appear as of now.. :

```
<?php
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   include('connect.php');

   if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password'])){
    $uname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['username']);
    $pword  = password_hash(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['firstname']);
    $lname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['lastname']);

    $username  = trim($uname);
    $password  = trim($pword);
    $firstname = trim($fname);
    $lastname  = trim($lname);
    $admin = "0";

        $query  = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count == 0){
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, lastname, admin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $admin);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
        else {
            $msg  = "Användarnamn upptaget.. ";
        }
   }
        mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Well, nothing just happens when the ajax call is executed, cant see any syntax errors, but maybe you can. Thanks beforehand.

I get these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /customers/5/0/5/xxxxxx/php/register.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement in /customers/5/0/5/xxxxx/php/register.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /customers/5/0/5/xxxxx/php/register.php(25):    mysqli_stmt_execute(Object(mysqli_stmt))
#1 {main}
thrown in /customers/5/0/5/xxxxxxx/php/register.php on line 25
```

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX call is even being made. Try checking the console for errors

Comment: And is the item inserted into the database? The PHP script doesn't return anything at all, so it probably just times out and hits the error handler

Comment: @adeneo The item is not inserted, that is the issue. The ajax call is being made, it goes all the way to "success", no console errors

Comment: @DouglasPettersson,your page will refresh on submit? yes or no

Comment: And if you echo back `mysqli_error($conn)` to the ajax  call, there are no errors

Comment: @EaBangalore - it will refresh on submit, but the button being clicked is a DIV

Comment: Page does not refresh on submit, exactly what i am trying to avoid with ajax

Comment: How do i echo back something from the php @adeneo ?

Comment: @DouglasPettersson,then don't specify any method in form like         <form method="GET">
you are using

Comment: @DouglasPettersson, you cannot send data in get method like so         data:{ username: username, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },

Comment: @EaBangalore - not specifying the method defaults to GET, same as it is. You can't submit a form from clicking on a DIV. Also, yes, you can submit data like that with `$.ajax`, regardless of what method you use.

Comment: @DouglasPettersson,you need to encode data otherwise use $.post method so that you can access data in php like this way $_POST["data"]

Comment: Firstly, edit the ajax function to [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/7vv7bxm5/1/), then in the PHP script, at the bottom **before** you close the db connection, you add `echo mysqli_error($conn);` to see if there are any errors, they'd show up in the console

Comment: @adeneo My post is now updated with errors, fixed a few,but these i dont get.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

This line was incorrect since i was not using enough characters to bind the values.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, **"sss"**, $username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $admin);
```

Should be like:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, **"sssss"**, $username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $admin);
```

PLUS

The $conn in

```
 mysqli_real_escape_string(-->$conn<--, $_GET['password']);
```

was missing.